# How can I combine these two individual FFmpeg commands into one command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two FFmpeg overlay commands. Can these two scripts be combined into one

Fix top:

```
ffmpeg -i final.mp4 -i "logo.mov" -filter_complex "[1:v:0]scale=100:-1[inner];[0:v:0][inner]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,5)',drawtext=fontfile=C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2:x=5:y=50:text=@(youraccountname):enable='between(t,0,5)'[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a? TOP.mp4
```

Fix top final with bottom:

```
ffmpeg -i TOP.mp4 -i "logo.mov" -filter_complex "[1:v:0]scale=100:-1[inner];[0:v:0][inner]overlay=main_w-(overlay_w+10):main_h-(overlay_h+10):enable='between(t,6,10)',drawtext=fontfile=C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2:x=220:y=720:text=@(youraccountname):enable='between(t,6,10)'[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a? FIXa.mp4
```

Comment: Need to see complete output of `ffmpeg -i final.mp4 -i logo.mov`

Comment: @llogan thanks for attention mate,  for the final output is expected like this 
[Complete output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DkLdWUpsUCcao33xmIaDoEZ6qqSmSHmH/view?usp=sharing) , my hope logo.mov and username appear every 5 seconds and move from the header and footer 

really appreciate with your help

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the log from the command that I was looking for. *"my hope logo.mov and username appear every 5 seconds and move from the header and footer"* This changes everything. Your requirements change too often. This happened in the last question of yours I answered. I gave an answer that directly answered the question, then you asked for more in a comment. I don't have the time or motivation to answer questions like that. You should state what you actually want to do in the initial question instead of making changes in follow-up comments.

Comment: thank you, sir, for being very helpful, forgive me if my question is getting further from the initial context of what I asked @llogan